# Mass Record insert using Salesforce connection for two org

Tags: apex, data-loader, salesforce2salesforce

I have created a salesforce to salesforce connection using trigger for new record and for update using the basic functionality.

But as during the deployment I may be need to put million of data and in this particular scenario I can't use trigger for mass transfer.

Is there any other way to use connection of salesforce to salesforce and do mass transfer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write `Apex Batch Class` for doing the mass transfer. In the execute method you can insert the `PartnerNetworkRecordConnection` object.

Below is the sample code i.e. not compiled for mass transferring the `Account` object if `Publish and Subscribe` is done in respective Org.

```
global class ShareAccount implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
  global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
      return Database.getQueryLocator([Select Id from Account]); 
  }

  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
    //GET THE CONNECTION ID FROM PARTNERNETWORKCONNECTION WHERE THE RECORDS NEEDS TO BE SHARED CONSIDERING THE CONNECTION IS ONLY 1
    List<PartnerNetworkConnection> pncList = [SELECT Id 
                                              FROM PartnerNetworkConnection 
                                              WHERE ConnectionStatus = 'Accepted' LIMIT 1]

    List<PartnerNetworkRecordConnection> pnrcInsertList = new List<PartnerNetworkRecordConnection>();
    if(!pncList.isEmpty()) {
        //LOOP THROUGH ALL THE ACCOUNT FOR SHARING THE ACCOUNT
        for(Account accObj : scope){
                pnrcInsertList.add(new PartnerNetworkRecordConnection( ConnectionId  = pncList[0].Id,
                                                                       LocalRecordId = accObj.Id,
                                                                       SendEmails    = FALSE));
        }
    }

    if(!pnrcInsertList.isEmpty()) {
        insert pnrcInsertList;
    }
  }

  global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){       
  }
}
```

Note: You can write the batch class for initial transfer and then you can utilize the trigger code

Comment: Thanks for this , But other that if externally we are trying to do is there any trick that can help us so. Cheers !